# Powershell Servermanager module not included in Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows

This is driving me nuts!

Apparently using the servermanager module should be as easy as type:

```
Import-Module servermanager
```

The problem is that I don't have it.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Module -ListAvailable


    Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Name                                ExportedCommands                                           
---------- ----                                ----------------                                           
Manifest   BitsTransfer                        {Add-BitsFile, Remove-BitsTransfer, Complete-BitsTransfe...
Manifest   CimCmdlets                          {Get-CimAssociatedInstance, Get-CimClass, Get-CimInstanc...
Script     ISE                                 {New-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, Get-IseSnippet}        
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics    {Get-WinEvent, Get-Counter, Import-Counter, Export-Count...
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           {Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript}                        
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-ItemProperty, Join-Pa...
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {Get-Acl, Set-Acl, Get-PfxCertificate, Get-Credential...}  
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Format-Wide...} 
Manifest   Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Disable-WSManCredSSP, Enable-WSManCredSSP, Get-WSManCre...
Script     PSDiagnostics                       {Disable-PSTrace, Disable-PSWSManCombinedTrace, Disable-...
Binary     PSScheduledJob                      {New-JobTrigger, Add-JobTrigger, Remove-JobTrigger, Get-...
Manifest   TroubleshootingPack                 {Get-TroubleshootingPack, Invoke-TroubleshootingPack}      
Manifest   WebAdministration                   {Start-WebCommitDelay, Stop-WebCommitDelay, Get-WebConfi...


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Name                                ExportedCommands                                           
---------- ----                                ----------------                                           
Manifest   SQLASCMDLETS                        {Add-RoleMember, Backup-ASDatabase, Invoke-ASCmd, Invoke...
Manifest   SQLPS                               {Backup-SqlDatabase, Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase, Disabl...
```

Any attempt to search in Google "Install servemanager module" returns thousands of pages to install things using the servermanager module! :-\

I'm using an up-to-date copy of Windows Web Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1, and Powershell v4.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you running? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major`

Comment: I'm using version 4.0

Comment: Oh dear... I just found it! It's in "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\" Why is not in "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules"???

Comment: In your code snippit above you show it's NOT in the system32 directory.  You responded to Nathan's answer saying it wasn't in that directory either.  Could you mean that you found it in the windows on windows directory?

Comment: I got the above ouput using Powershell-ISE 64. When I run it with Powershell-ISE 32 it founds it.

Comment: So the answer is to use the x64 version of powershell?  If you type that up as the answer, we'll likely upvote it.

Comment: Actually the answer is to use the 32-bit version of Powershell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved!
I had to use the 32-bit version of Powerhell as the module is in the folder:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

Comment: Add this line to your profile so the modules are loaded each time: `$env:PSModulePath = "$env:PSModulePath;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;"`

Answer (score 1):

Look in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` and you should see a `ServerManager` folder. If you do not, then the module isn't available.

As far as I know, this module is only available on 2008 R2 *Standard* and above. My 2008 (non-R2) server lacked it, but my standard one has it. Also, make sure you're using the 64-bit PowerShell and not 32-bit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The module is not in that folder. And thanks for your suggestion. I'm using powershell-ISE 64bit as Administrator