# Powershell module 'servermanager' not found on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am running windows 10 on a virtual machine and I would like to list the windows feature available by running the following commands on powershell:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Get-WindowsFeature
```

Already running the first command produces: The specific module 'servermanager' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

I have tried to use the solution for Windows server 2008 
[Powershell Servermanager module not included in Windows Web Server 2008 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/646136/powershell-servermanager-module-not-included-in-windows-web-server-2008-r2) but that does not work for me, i.e. I cannot find the module in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules. Yet, I could not find how to switch between 64bit or 32bit Powershell in Windows 10. Any help? thank you

Comment: I think this is only part of the Server, so try Server 2016 Preview4

Comment: I have tried to solve this, and have not.  I found https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/drew/2016/12/23/installing-remote-server-admin-tools-rsat-via-powershell/  , but the powershel cmds above still fail.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to download and install 'Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10'. The download link is https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=45520

**RSAT tools on Windows 10 October 2018 Update or later**

> Starting with Windows 10 October 2018 Update, RSAT is included as a
>   set of "Features on Demand" right from Windows 10. Do not download an
>   RSAT package from this page. Instead, just go to "Manage optional
>   features" in Settings and click "Add a feature" to see the list of
>   available RSAT tools. Select and install the specific RSAT tools you
>   need. To see installation progress, click the Back button to view
>   status on the "Manage optional features" page.

[image: Optional features - Add a feature - RSAT: Server Manager]

Comment: Which RSAT tool do I need?

Comment: @AlxVallejo: You need "RSAT: ServerManager" to do Import-Module ServerManager.

Comment: On Win 11, Settings -> apps, is supposed to have "optional features" between "offline maps" and "apps for websites", but it is missing. Control panel -> Programs -> Turn windows features on or off, does not seem to list any RSAT feature. Why is this impossible?

Comment: It was moved to Settings -> System -> optional features. Ugh.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the x86 tag to identify which PS version you are starting up. See following picture:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, I have tried to look into the 32bit version of Powershell but still I cannot run/find the 'servermanager' module...

Comment: You need the 64bit version.

Comment: It is not true for me, I run `Get-Module -ListAvailable` on 64bit version of PS and the module I need is not on the list.

Comment: So non of the installations (32 & 64? has this module?

Comment: Exactly, non of them (32bit and 64bit) has it.

Answer (score 3):

An addendum to [Kieren Dixon's excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/a/831836/137255), if when installing the required optional feature in Win10 you see `not installed`, you can complete the below steps (based on [this blog post](https://www.wincert.net/microsoft-windows/windows-10/cannot-install-rsat-tools-on-windows-10-1809-error0x80244022/)) to resolve the issue:

- Run PowerShell as administrator.
- Run the below commands

```
# make note of the current value, so we can reset it later
$UseWUServer = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:/Software/Policies/Microsoft/Windows/WindowsUpdate/AU' 'UseWUServer'

# ensure when we fetch properties we're pulling from MS; not some internal server which may not have the solution we need
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:/Software/Policies/Microsoft/Windows/WindowsUpdate/AU' 'UseWUServer' 0

# restart the windows update service so our change takes effect
Restart-Service 'wuauserv'

# install the required feature(s)
@(
    'RSAT.ServerManager.Tools*' 
    'RSAT.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools*' 
) |
    ForEach-Object { Get-WindowsCapability -Name $_ -Online } |
    ForEach-Object { Add-WindowsCapability -Name $_.Name -Online }

# (optional) put things back how we found them
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:/Software/Policies/Microsoft/Windows/WindowsUpdate/AU' 'UseWUServer' $UseWUServer
Restart-Service 'wuauserv'

# (optional) Display the features
Get-WindowsCapability -Name 'RSAT.*' -Online | 
    Sort-Object State, Name |
    Format-Table Name, State, DisplayName -AutoSize

# (optional) Test the AD module (module should automatically be imported)
Get-AdUser $env:USERNAME
```

If you have policies that are pushing Windows Update settings to the correlated registry keys, giving it a reboot afterwards should put any changes back in place if they were adjusted with this solution.

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot find path 'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU' 
because it does not exist.` on the first line.
Windows 10 Pro x64 v1909 (18363.1379)